# Force node to use TLSv1.2 when connecting to a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, tls1.2, fix-protocol

I'm using Node as a client to connect to a FIX server. The FIX server only accepts connections using TLSv1.2. This is how I'm trying to connect to the server.

```
const tls = require('tls');
const options = {
  host,
  port,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  // secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method',
  // maxVersion: 'TLSv1.2',
};
const socket = tls.connect(options, () => {
  const tlsSocket = new tls.TLSSocket(socket);
  const protocol = tlsSocket.getProtocol();

  console.log('inside -', protocol);
});
```

I've tried both maxVersion and secureProtocol properties but it still uses TLSv1.3.
I also tried using cli option --tls-max-v1.2 and setting

```
tls.DEFAULT_MAX_VERSION = 'TLSv1.2'
```

but it still uses TLSv1.3.

Can some help me regarding this ? Thanks.

Comment: If the server only supports 1.2, how can it the connect callback show 1.3?

Comment: It's a FIX server. It connects perfectly but when you send a logon message it disconnects. I asked the support guy and he said that you should use TLSv1.2. Also when I connect to some other server which does not have this requirement the log still shows TLSv1.3.